# Show overflow of rendered HTML for Rich Text Editor column in Sharepoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I'm trying to show the overflow of rendered HTML in a rich text editor column for a sharepoint list.
I would like the complete rendered html to be visible in list view. Currently I can get the column to display the full content, but the full content is shown in raw html, not the rendered html which I would like it to be.

I feel like there has to be a way, since I'm so close..
Bulletins in the image below is a sharepoint list.
[image]

I've found articles saying that an SPFx Framework connector is needed to do this.
I am new to sharepoint and am wondering if anyone has a simpler solution. If not is there any example sharepoint framework connector article to get this done.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rich text columns show fine in modern list views. It has to be enhanced Rich Text, though, not plain text with HTML tags. Here's a screenshot of a modern list view I just built:

[image]

Edit: Note that Rich Text columns don't render in JSON formatting of the modern list views and short of installing a custom SPFx solution, there is really nothing you can do about that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to show the overflow for a rich text column. But when I go to edit the json format of the column, the rich text gets displayed in raw html. Is there a way to keep the rendered html while also showing the overflow for the column.

Comment: OK, you fail to mention that you are using JSON formatting for the column or the view. JSON formatting does not support Rich Text. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: do you have any leads on an custom spfx solution example. It seems like a lot of people are looking for this, but there really are not example solutions shown anywhere